# Cannot call method "on" of undefined (express and socket.io)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want to export the socket.io object from my app.js of express

My app.js file is here: http://pastebin.com/Kfny4yVK

My bin/www file is here: http://pastebin.com/qGhPm6KE

In my app.js I do:

```
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
exports.io = io;
```

In a routes file I do:

```
var io = require(__dirname+'/../app.js').io;
```

However, when I call the:

```
io.on
```

I get an undefined object error. Any idea why this is happening? It looks like nodejs is somehow modifying the io object at export? Is this possible? Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: The code independently operates fine. Without seeing your application further I can only guess, but it's possible that your routes module is being loaded before the app can instantiate the io server.

Comment: You have to export variables from apps.js that you want other modules to be able to access.

Comment: Jeff, I am adding my app.js and bin/www files, I think you are on the right track. But I still can't figure out this one

Answer (score 2):

With Express v4.x I use the following to export the socket.io object.

APP.JS

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
//Export sio module so socket.io can be used in other modules
module.exports.sio = io;   //ADDED this
```

OTHER_FILE.JS

```
//Import sio module from app.js
var io = require('../app.js').sio;
```

Comment: Thanks, how is that different from my setup above?

Comment: Yes, module.exports.io=io and exports.io = io should be the exact same. But this code definately works for me with socket.io V1.x and Express v4.x. I know you are finding an io object but  TO BE SURE TO BE SURE check the server.js require path. Add var path=require('path').  console.log("__dirname+'/../app.js' = %s", path.resolve(__dirname+'/../app.js')); You should see path to server.js. If so there is nothing wrong with your code in my opinion and issue lies elsewhere.